# Example SVG code?

Tags: svg

Can anyone point me to a good source of example SVG code?

Google charts would be good, but I haven't worked out how to find the SVG. Presumably the browser does actually see SVG at some point - anyone know how I can intercept this?

Thanks -

Al

Comment: Forgot to say - I'm interested in drawing interactive charts, hence the Google question. General output from something like svg-edit/Inkscape/Kiyut/Karbon/etc probably wouldn't help much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're interested in interactive svg charts, definitely check out [d3.js](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/). It's pretty awesome.

In addition, you might want to take a look at [this svg reference](http://commons.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/SVG_Essentials).

Oh, and regarding google chart svg: just use chrome inspector or firebug to look at/copy the svg.

Comment: Opera Dragonfly: http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/ and the IE9+ devtools also come to mind.

Comment: Thanks - this is all new to me. The book looked good, but even the first example in the book, and the full cat example, won't render in FF, Chrome, or ScriptDraw, so I've given up on it.

Comment: Jeez, I hate this edit interface. Next go: Firebug was interesting. It shows the HTML incorrectly, and cut/paste code won't render. I eventually checked it against Inspector. Inspector shows rect elements as <rect ....></rect>. Firebug shows them as <rect ...>, and misses out the final '/' (it should have showed <rect .../>. Saving HTML changes in Firebug, and even showing all the HTML so that you can copy it, seems to be impossible. I've given up on it.

Comment: Hmm, difficult to say w/o any code. If you need help, just open another thread, post some code and we'll help. Good luck with everything!